# User-defined function with dplyr - mutate column is a argument

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, dplyr

I would like to create a defined function with dplyr in R. But I stuck in passing argument in mutate function. I have two datasets.

data1:

| GROUP | AGEGRP | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 15 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 |

data2:

| GROUP | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 15 |

My function is

```
freqcnt <- function(var) {
  var <- enquo(var)
  
  data2 <- data2 %>%
    mutate(!!var = 99)
  
  data1 <- data1 %>%
    rbind(data2) %>%
    return()
}
```

When I run the following code,

```
df <- freqcnt(AGEGRP)
```

the error message is popped up.

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"    
    mutate(!!var ="
```

However, if I remove !!, then var will become the name of variable instead of AGEGRP. Please show me some lights. Thanks,

Comment: Can't really test it, but I believe instead of `=` you need to use the walrus operator ':=' when using a quasi-quotation on the left-had-side of the equation. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295654/dplyr-non-standard-evaluation-and-walrus-operator-and-curly-curly).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fix to your function.

```
library(dplyr)

freqcnt <- function(var){
  
  data2 <- data2 %>%
    mutate({{var}} := 99)

  data1 <- data1 %>%
    rbind(data2)
    
    return(data1)
  
}

freqcnt("AGEGRP")
#   GROUP AGEGRP COUNT
# 1     1      0    15
# 2     2      1    20
# 3     3     99    15
```

By the way, since you are using `dplyr`. I suggest you can use the `bind_rows` function instead of `rbind`. It can combine data frames with different column names, leaving those unmatched column `NA`. Below is a function I proposed. You don't need to specify the column names anymore. Furthermore, I design it to be able to take an argument `fill` as the value to fill in the unmatched columns.

```
freqcnt2 <- function(fill){
  data1 <- data1 %>%
    bind_rows(data2) %>%
    mutate(across(.fns = function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), fill, x)))
  return(data1)
}

freqcnt2(99)
#   GROUP AGEGRP COUNT
# 1     1      0    15
# 2     2      1    20
# 3     3     99    15
```

**DATA**

```
data1 <- data.frame(GROUP = 1:2,
                    AGEGRP = 0:1,
                    COUNT = c(15,20))

data2 <- data.frame(GROUP = 3, COUNT = 15)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can I ask why we need two {} and := here? I actual do some data manipulation like left join and group by in the function too. If I use enquo and !!, I can successfully pass arguments as columns in %>%. Then I use your script mutate({{var}} := 99), which generate the correct result I want!!

Comment: Thanks for freqcnt2. Because I also do other calculations and manipulations, I will see how mutate part can fit in my function better!

Comment: @Jemc36 See this to learn why we use `{{`: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this really all you need:

```
    freqcnt <- function(var) {
        var <- as.character(substitute(var))
        data2[,var] <- 99
        return( rbind( data1, data2 ) )
    }
```

People have this obsession with tidyversyficationism at times.