# Understanding curly-curly operator

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

How does that code works? The main goal was to asign a string to a variable and then make a dataframe which the first column is the string.
So in this case you could do that:

```
# column1 <- "Student Name"
df1 <- tibble(`Student Name` = rep('fill', 3))
```

But that's not the challenge.

If you try this:

```
column1 <- "Student Name"
df1 <- tibble(`column1` = rep('fill', 3))
```

It doesn't work as well.

So, browsing in the internet i found this solution, and it works

```
column1 <- "Student Name"
df1 <- tibble({{column1}} := rep('fill', 3))
```

But still, i don't know how this code works, i know that he uses curly curly operator, which i've never seen before, and this ':=' operator as well. Can someone explain how does that work? I've searched for this curlycurly operator but was a little bit hard to comprehend.

Comment: See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#indirection

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295654/dplyr-non-standard-evaluation-and-walrus-operator-and-curly-curly and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62791997/what-is-the-embracing-operator. Do you have a question beyond what those answers covered?